# Can I solve this problem using ParametricNDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, parametric-functions

Is this the correct way to solve this problem?

```
d = {{9.721036901*10^-7, 0.80119823*10^-6}, {9.728704323*10^-7, 0.83015194*10^-6}, {9.728577185000001*10^-7, 0.857031534*10^-6},{9.728430487000002*10^-7, 0.88804645*10^-6}, {9.733506242*10^-7, 0.914930348*10^-6}, {9.733359543*10^-7, 0.945945264*10^-6}};

b = Interpolation[d, InterpolationOrder -> 1];

bb = b[a]*10^-4;

yF = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y'[t] == bb y[t], y[0] == 1}, y, {t, 0, 10}, {a}]
```

Comment: What you want to achieve?

Comment: What is "this problem"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've done everything right.

```
yF = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y'[t] == bb y[t], y[0] == 1}, y, {t, 0, 10}, {a}];
Plot[Evaluate@Table[Callout[yF[a][t], a], {a, 0, 5}], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]